# Implementation of a navigation menu on a website. What script is it implemented on?

Tags: javascript, menu, navigation

I found a good example of a vertical menu on the website https://zooatlanta.org/. But I can't find the script for this menu. Does anyone know what script this is implemented in, or are there similar examples of scripts for implementing such a vertical menu? thanks in advance

links to the resource of this script, or example scripts for similar examples of a vertical menu

Comment: Have you tried opening the browser's Web Developer Tools, selecting the Inspector tab, and then clicking on the vertical menu? This will display the relevant HTML, JS and CSS.